# Response descriptor without root Json element

Tags: ios, json, restkit

```
{
    "id": 76,
    "name": "Tom Timberley",
    "gender": 1,
    "follower_count": 1,
    "following_count": 1,
    "me_following": [{
        "id": 5,
        "status": "ACCEPTED",
        "following_me": {
            "id": 2,
            "status": "ACCEPTED"
        }
    }]
}
```

There is no outer Json object. Is there any way i can access the root object from object `following_me` when i do `RKRelationshipMapping`?

I have tables `Following_me` and `User` and I want to map the root of Json which is the user data to `Following_me`.

```
[following_me_mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"@root" toKeyPath:@"user" withMapping:userMapping]];
```

Here `following_me_mapping` is the mapping for `Following_me` table and `userMapping` is the mapping for `User` table.

But specifying `@root` is not working.

```
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                        pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:nil
                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
 ];
```

This is how i add the response descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be thinking about the problem backwards and being confused about what your response descriptor is processing.

By setting `pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil` your response descriptor is going to be active for any request you make (it isn't filtered by path pattern) and is going to process the JSON payload from the root (there is no key path to navigate to).

So, your initial mapping is already supposed to deal with the root. Then you add a relationship for `me_following` key to process that content. In that mapping you add a relationship for `following_me`.

In this way you drill down through the data mapping it as you go, rather than your description which says you want to drill in to begin with and then try to navigate back out again (which requires a rather different and more complex approach).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use "MJExtension.Framework" for "json to model" data(https://github.com/CoderMJLee/MJExtension), display those data onto a model rather than a json data(dictionary) could simplify ur question , best wishes!~~

Comment: Yes, But I am using the Restkit mapping in-order to write Json response to core-data, it would be great if I can do this with Restkit itself.

Comment: ok,i see this Restkit mapping,it's actually multi-useful,if u have most of time and u can study on it.But for me,i need to do some shortcuts for project.Could you give some links or resources for this kit to me?  3Q~

Comment: Their documentation itself is the best place to start plus it works on top of Core-data [Restkit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

Answer (score 0):

```
yes you can save the array of dictionary.allkeys, then put it in the for loop.


let arrayOFKeys = dictionary.allKeys
for(int i=0;i<arrayOFKeys.count;i++)
{
 dictionary.valueforKey(arrayOFKeys.objectAtIndex[i]) // here you will get value and key(root) as well
//key = arrayOFKeys.objectAtIndex[i]
//value = dictionary.valueforKey(arrayOFKeys.objectAtIndex[i])

}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i achieve this using RKRelationshipmapping

Comment: ohhh pardon me , i've never used RKRelationshipmapping